# Receive link from row in views-template file

Tags: views

I changed a views-template and wanted to link all elements together. Is there a different way as getting the link via regular expressions?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to be a bit more descriptive. What template did you change? What does the code look like now? What does it mean to "link all elements together" ?

Comment: Sorry... so I changed the views-view-fields--myview.tpl.php template.

the title-field has the link to its node, but I want to have that link over an image-field, the title field and another description-field altogether (not all for themselfes)

Answer (score 2):

Have you try the option in the field to "Reqrite the output" ?
[image: Rewrite the output of this field]

First of all, you select "Exclude from display" in the fields you want to group together, then in the last field you rewrite its output using patterns. This allow you to put HTML or text before your fields for example something like this:

```
<strong>Address</strong>
City: [field_city_value]<br />
Country: [field_country_value]
```

Then you also have the option to "Output this field as a link" which allows you to give your group of field a link. This option also provides a way to rewrite the link with patterns.